# Restore downloaded database from server in application

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, restore

My created database file is originally in .sqlite format.I have uploaded a the file on server by converting it in sql format. I converted it back in .sqlite format and successfully downloaded the file in my application. But now when I again try to do operations taking that downloaded file, my application crashes down. I checked the error from logcat and it shows error on line db.execSQL(query). Can you help me with some way of solving this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post your log cat? Check for the database and its table

Comment: 12-19 05:30:59.227: E/SQLiteLog(22549): (1) table patient already exists
12-19 05:30:59.367: E/AndroidRuntime(22549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 05:30:59.367: E/AndroidRuntime(22549):  at com.example.database_project.SQLiteController.onCreate(SQLiteController.java:50)

This is shown in logcat and when i double click on the com.example.database_project.SQLiteController.onCreate(SQLiteController.java:50), it shows error on line db.execSQL(query).

Comment: i think you are executing the query like creating the table_patient.Check whether the table already exists or not before executing the query